# Rational mathematical expression too long for overleaf?

Tags: equations, formatting

first of all, I don't know why this isn't going into LaTeX formatting.. I assumed on this stack exchange that would be easy to do. But yeah, I have this function, and it turns out it evaluates to a pretty nasty rational function of two variables, here t and v. When I put this on my overleaf document, it goes off the page. What can I do?? Can I make the text smaller somehow? How do I do that? Are there any other options? Thanks!!

```
$$W_{(2)}(t,v)=\frac{t^{2-k}\,v^{k-2}\,\left(t\,v-1\right)\,\left(v-1\right)\,
\left(t-v+t^2\,v^2+t^3\,v^2+t^4\,v^2-t^5\,v^2-t\,v-t^4\,v-t^5\,v-t^{3\,k}\,
t^2-t^{3\,k}\,t^4+t^2+t^3-t\,t^{3\,k}\,v^2+t^{3\,k}\,t^2\,v+t^{3\,k}\,
t^3\,v+t^{3\,k}\,t^4\,v-t^{3\,k}\,t^3\,v^2+t\,t^{3\,k}\,v-1\right)}%
{{\left(t-1\right)}^4\,{\left(t+1\right)}^2\,\left(t^4+t^3+2\,t^2+t+1\right)}$$
```

Comment: What are all these commas in the numerator and denominator?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "too long for overleaf". Please clarify.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure. This code was generated by matlab.

Comment: @Mico When i copy this code into overleaf, the expression goes off the page. Like, in microsoft word the expression would just start a new line, but with overleaf it is not so. I tied switching it to landscape mode, but it still goes off the page.

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa - Please see the answer I just posted, in which I show two possibilities for displaying `W_{(2)}(t,v)`.

Comment: @Bernard - The commas were an artifact of the site software. Once the code was pretty-printed, all instances of `,` were revealed to actually by `\,` (thinspace).

Comment: with reference to your first comment in the question post, unlike the math and physics stackexchange we do not enable mathjax on this site to allow a latex-like rendering of mathematics in the page, mathjax is good software but it is javascript not tex so it would be too confusing to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's *possible*, though not really recommended, to line-break the very long numerator twice and to display `W_{(2)}(t,v)` as one big fraction.

You would do your readers a big favor if you display the numerator and denominator terms separately.

Either way, I'd get rid of the many `\,` spacers, and I'd eliminate the many `\left` and `\right` directives as they don't actually do anything (except create code clutter).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\begin{document}

\[
W_{(2)}(t,v)=\frac{\left(
\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{\raggedright
$t^{2-k} v^{k-2} (tv-1) (v-1) [t-v+t^2 v^2+t^3 
v^2+t^4 v^2-t^5 v^2-t v-t^4 v-t^5 v-t^{3k} t^2-t^{3k} 
t^4+t^2+t^3-t t^{3k} v^2+t^{3k} t^2 v+t^{3k} t^3 v+t^{3k} 
t^4 v-t^{3k} t^3 v^2+t t^{3k} v-1]$}\right)}{%
(t-1)^4 (t+1)^2 (t^4+t^3+2 t^2+t+1)}
\]

\bigskip
\noindent
$W_{(2)}(t,v)\equiv A(t,v)/B(t)$, where 
\begin{align*}
A(t,v) &= t^{2-k} v^{k-2} (tv-1) (v-1) [t-v+t^2 v^2+t^3 
v^2+t^4 v^2-t^5 v^2\\
&\qquad -t v-t^4 v-t^5 v-t^{3k} t^2-t^{3k} 
t^4+t^2+t^3-t t^{3k} v^2\\
&\qquad +t^{3k} t^2 v+t^{3k} t^3 v+t^{3k} 
t^4 v-t^{3k} t^3 v^2+t t^{3k} v-1]
\end{align*}
and
$B(t)=(t-1)^4 (t+1)^2 (t^4+t^3+2 t^2+t+1)$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow,  good job cleaning up the code. Did oyu do that by hand? IDK what all these /left and /right and comma's are doing in the code. Like i said, the code was generated by MatLab. Your code is much cleaner though.

Comment: so the spaces \, don't do anything really? Cool thx man ur the best

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa - I deleted all `\,` spacers and the `\left` and `\right` modifiers by hand. Encasing the numerator in a `\parbox`, it became reasonably straightforward to choose some line breaks. It was at that point, though, that I decided it would be much nicer to display the numerator and denominator separately...

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa - The `\,` spacers, well, insert "thinspace". It's just not typographically appropriate, let alone necessary, to insert all those thinspaces.

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa - You may want to go through the code and straighten out the way some of the powers of `t` are displayed. E.g., replace `t t^{3k}` with`t^{3k+1}`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to learn about all the formatting techniques you used here, but it's exactly what I was looking for. U da bomb!!

Answer (score 1):

Ì propose this variant layout, with `gather*` and `multlined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
W_{(2)}(t,v) =\frac{t^{2-k} v^{k-2} (tv-1) (v-1)A(t, v)}{(t-1)^4 (t+1)^2 (t^4+t^3+2 t^2+t+1)}, \\
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{multlined}
A(t, v) = t-v+t^2 v^2+t^3v^2+t^4 v^2-t^5 v^2 -t v-t^4 v-t^5 v -t^{3k} t^2-t^{3k}t^4\\
+t^2+t^3-t\, t^{3k} v^2+t^{3k} t^2 v+t^{3k} t^3 v+t^{3k}t^4 v-t^{3k} t^3 v^2+t\, t^{3k} v-1.
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So many interesting environments I need to learn about.. Thanks man!!

Comment: I think the `mathtools` package, which extends `amsmath`,  should be systematically loaded. B.t.w., I forgot to mention you should not use `$$ ... $$` for displayed equetions, as it is plain TeX syntax, and it can lead to inconsistent vertical spacing with LaTeX. Use the `\[ ... \]` syntax instead.